# scss styling not getting applied

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

```
<body>

    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#history">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>   

    <div id="firstRow>
        <a id="about" class="smooth"></a>
        About page goes here.
    </div> 

    ...

    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Here is how my HTML looks like and the below is the scss that I wrote

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;

  div{

    #firstRow {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
  }

  }

}
```

But the style is not getting applied. I followed the scss guide, but it is not working.

Comment: It should be working unless you did not compile the `.scss` file

Comment: You're nesting `#firstRow` inside of `div`, creating the selector `div #firstRow`. If you understand basic CSS, you'd know why that isn't selecting any element on your page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"` missing in the `<div id="firstRow">` tag id

```
<body>

  <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#history">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>   

    <div id="firstRow">
        <a id="about" class="smooth"></a>
        About page goes here.
    </div> 

    ...

    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Updated SCSS script, you are referring div element child of #firstRow in SCSS but HTML refer same element.

$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

```
body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;

  div#firstRow {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
  }

}
```

Or change your HTML code like below

```
<div>
    <a id="about" class="smooth"></a>

    <div id="firstRow">
      About page goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```